# Rust "doesn't have a size known at compile-time" error for iterators?

Tags: rust, cartesian-product

I'm refactoring the cartesian product code in Rust's itertools [1] as a way of learning Rust. The cartesian product is formed from an Iterator I and an IntoIterator J. The IntoIterator J is converted into an iterator multiple times and iterated over.

So far I have the code below, which is a minor modification of the code in the itertools source code. The biggest change is specifying a specific type (i8) instead of using generic types.

```
struct Product {
    a: dyn Iterator<Item=i8>,
    a_cur: Option<i8>,
    b: dyn IntoIterator<Item=i8, IntoIter=dyn Iterator<Item=i8>>,
    b_iter: dyn Iterator<Item=i8>
}


impl Iterator for Product {

    type Item = (i8, i8);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let elt_b = match self.b_iter.next() {
            None => {
                self.b_iter = self.b.into_iter();
                match self.b_iter.next() {
                    None => return None,
                    Some(x) => {
                        self.a_cur = self.a.next();
                        x
                    }
                }
            }
            Some(x) => x
        };
        match self.a_cur {
            None => None, 
            Some(ref a) => {
                Some((a, elt_b))
            }
        }

    }

}


fn cp(i: impl Iterator<Item=i8>, j: impl IntoIterator<Item=i8>) -> Product {
    
   let p = Product{
       a: i, 
       a_cur: i.next(), 
       b: j, 
       b_iter: j.into_iter()};
   return p

}



fn main() {

    for foo in cp(vec![1,4,7], vec![2,3,9]) {
        println!("{:?}", foo);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the compiler is giving errors I have been unable to fix. I've attempted the fixes suggested by the compiler, but when I make them I get many more "doesn't have size known at compile time" errors.

I'm especially confused because the implementation in Rust's itertools library (link below) has a very similar structure and didn't require specifying lifetimes, borrowing, using Boxes, or the dyn keyword. I'd love to know what I changed that led to the Rust compiler suggesting using borrowing and/or Boxes.

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Iterator<Item = i8> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:15:8
   |
15 |     a: dyn Iterator<Item=i8>,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Iterator<Item = i8> + 'static)`
   = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
   = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
   |
15 |     a: &dyn Iterator<Item=i8>,
   |        ^
help: the `Box` type always has a statically known size and allocates its contents in the heap
   |
15 |     a: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i8>>,
   |        ^^^^                     ^

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn IntoIterator<Item = i8, IntoIter = (dyn Iterator<Item = i8> + 'static)> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:17:8
   |
17 |     b: dyn IntoIterator<Item=i8, IntoIter=dyn Iterator<Item=i8>>,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn IntoIterator<Item = i8, IntoIter = (dyn Iterator<Item = i8> + 'static)> + 'static)`
   = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
   = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
   |
17 |     b: &dyn IntoIterator<Item=i8, IntoIter=dyn Iterator<Item=i8>>,
   |        ^
help: the `Box` type always has a statically known size and allocates its contents in the heap
   |
17 |     b: Box<dyn IntoIterator<Item=i8, IntoIter=dyn Iterator<Item=i8>>>,
   |        ^^^^                                                         ^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

[1] Docs at https://nozaq.github.io/shogi-rs/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product and code at https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/blob/master/src/adaptors/mod.rs#L286 .

Comment: They use generics, that's why. Whenever you call this function with some arguments, compiler generates a separate function code for these specific arguments (i.e. it perfectly knows types and their sizes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't just change the item type, you also removed the generic iterator. In the `itertools` crate, there is:

```
pub struct Product<I, J>
    where I: Iterator
{
    a: I,
…
```

Meaning that `a` is an iterator whose exact type will be specified by the user (but still at compile time).

You have removed the generic `I` parameter and instead you have written:

```
pub struct Product
{
    a: dyn Iterator<Item=i8>,
…
```

If that worked, it would mean that `a` is an iterator whose item type is `u8` *but whose exact type will be specified at runtime.* Therefore at compile-time the compiler can't know the exact type of `a` nor how much space it should allocate to store `a` inside `Product`.

If you want your cartesian product to work for any iterator whose items are `u8`, you need to keep the generic parameter `I` with an extra constraint:

```
pub struct Product<I, J>
    where I: Iterator<Item=u8>
{
    a: I,
…
```

And a similar change will be required for `J` in `impl Iterator`.